# How to optimize an if else if statement where previous ifs are not used in loop?

Tags: php

This is hypothetical code, assuming I have the following:

Let's say I have an array and it has lots of data, integers in this sample question, but it can ANY type of data that's already sorted in some fashion in regards to the if statements.

```
$a = array(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,...,9,9,9);
```

Let's say I have a for loop with numerous if else if statements, and those can have any criteria for doing something.

```
for($i=0; i<count($a); i++) {
    // these if statements can be anything and may or may not be related with $a
    if($a[$i] == 0 && $i < 10) { 
        // do something
    }
    else if($a[$i] == 1 && $i < 20) {
        // do something
    }
    else if($a[$i] == 2) {
        // do something
    }
    else if($a[$i] == 3) {
        // do something
    }

    // and so on
}
```

Now the question, after the first if statement iterations are done, it's never used. Once the for loop starts using the next if statement, the previous if statement(s) don't need to be evaluated again. It can use the first if statement n amount of times and so on and so forth.

Is there a way to optimize it so it doesn't have to go through all the previous if else if statements as it's looping through the data? Mind, the data can be anything, and the if statements can be any variety of conditions.

Is there a paradigm shift, that I don't see, that is required on how this should be coded up to provide optimal performance?

Comment: Maybe...keep a `currentTier` variable, check whether it needs to be updated (& do so) at the beginning of the loop, and then `switch` on that?

Comment: @Michelle: Same problem, basically. Once the tier is high enough, the first cases are always unused. Also, we're talking ranges here as well.

Comment: @Madara > I think it is possible to assign an index to each if() and then use a switch() for looking at the right index. If you don't put any break in each case you can move from if to if without having to evaluate the first ones

Comment: Logical comparisons are incredibly cheap operations in terms of processing time. As-written I would not really bother worrying about it. The exception to this would be if you're calling a function inside the `if` condition, which is where you could potentially see a performance hit.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to avoid? Having to perform the earlier check on the later data. That imply's that your data is sorted. If so, why not just have X while loops. Move the matching values to an $innerTempVariable and remove them from the outer $a variable as they are moved to the $innerTempVariable. You can even use callback and such to create a outer while loop of the inner functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). You would need to build a class that stored the methods to call to perform the statements. Consider a class like this:

```
class MyStatements {
    public function If0($a, $i) {
        if($a[$i] == 0 && $i < 10) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public function If1($a, $i) {
        if($a[$i] == 1 && $i < 20) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

you could then do something like this:

```
$stmts = new MyStatements();
for($i = 0; i < count($a); i++) {
    call_user_func_array(array($stmts, 'If' . strval($i)), array($a, $i));
}
```

Comment: This looks nice but wouldn't this be clearly worse performance wise ?

Comment: @koopajah, not really. It would still be an O(n) operation for the iteration.

Comment: Yeah but isn't there some costs implied by  call_user_func_array() here ?

Comment: @koopajah, yes but they would be nearly unmeasurable.

Comment: > it makes sense, I'm more used to C where the cost would be a lot more if the function is not inlined. And it kind of looks cleaner/easier to maintain. One issue would be that when you need to add a new if between two others you need to change all the functions names.

Comment: @koopajah, that is most certainly a caveat, and a good addition here.

Comment: $a[0], $a[1], $a[2] should all be using If0, but doesn't it go to If1 after the first iteration?

Comment: @rotaercz, you said as it iterates you don't need to evaluate the previous if statements, so each if statement is a different method.

Comment: Oh, I guess I wasn't clear. I meant once it starts using the next if statement, the previous if statement(s) don't need to be evaluated again. It can use the first if statment n amount of times and so on and so forth.

Comment: Updated question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are spinning your wheels.

If you have a lot of data, chances are, slowness is coming from the data source not the server-side calculations.

If you do anything, you should break up your data into chunks and run portions at-a-time.  And you would only need to do this if you are noticing slow load-times or bad top-load on your server.

Asynchronous connections allow you to do this with ease, using ajax you can connect to your server, pull a limited chunk of data, process it, then after that displays in the client browser, run the next chunk.  Anytime you use a Web site that queries large amounts of data (ie: facebook) it does it this way.

But again, don't over-think this.  You really don't need to make your procedure more complicated. If you really want a gold-star you can make an object-oriented class that processes all this for you, but I will not get into that.

Comment: (I will also add, if you are pulling incredibly large amounts of data you should also consider storing data in json strings sorted alphabetically which takes the majority of the burden off your server and if you are really cleaver you can push data to the client-side via localStorage (but don't go crazy with that)

Comment: I think this is the most logical response. If you have date that needs to be processed with logic, there is no getting around it; and there is going to be a cost.

Answer (score 0):

Break up your for statement into multiple for statements. For your example code:

```
for($i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if($a[$i] == 0) {
        //do something
    }
}

for($i=0; i<20; i++) {
    if($a[$i] == 1) {
        //do something
    }
}

for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {
    if($a[$i] == 2) {
        // do something
    }
    else if($a[$i] == 3) {
        // do something
    }
}

//etc...
```

Comment: This may actually be the best performance wise, but not entirely flexible.

Comment: @Madara I tried a solution with a while loop around a single for statement but then he is forced back into a multiple if statement scenario. This method isolates the incremental variable so that it doesn't have to be tested at all.

Comment: This doesn't acknowledge that the data can be anything, and the if statements can be any variety of conditions.

Comment: @rotaerz This works no matter what is in `$a` and no matter what your conditions are. `$a` values are only tested inside your `if` conditions as in your example. This meets your requirements because you no longer have to tests the value of `$i` on each iteration.

Comment: @ogc-nick Let's say I have a hundred different if statements, are you saying I should be writing the code as you showed? Also your second for loop starts from 10 and the third for loop start from 20. Notice in the above you would be losing data.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses something called "short-circuit evaluation," as many other modern languages do.  This means once the boolean expression has been determined to be true or false, the remaining pieces of the expression will not be evaluated.

So, you could introduce new boolean values (maybe an array of them) that tracks if a piece of code has been executed already, and if it has been, set it to false.  Then use this boolean as the first condition in the "if" expression.  PHP will recognize that the value of this one is set to false, and ignore the rest of the clause.  This is a pretty simple route, and would keep your code mostly structured the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.3+ then you can use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```php
$a = array(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,9,9,9);

$dispatch = array(
    0=>function() { echo "0"; },
    1=>function() { echo "1"; },
    2=>function() { echo "2"; },
    3=>function() { echo "3"; },
    9=>function() { echo "9"; }
);

foreach ($a as $i)
{
    $dispatch[$i]();
}
```

Before PHP 5.3 you would have to use a map to function names, but the bottom works in PHP 5.3+ as well.

```php
$a = array(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,9,9,9);

function foo0()  { echo "0"; }
function foo1()  { echo "1"; }
function foo2()  { echo "2"; }
function foo3()  { echo "3"; }
function foo9()  { echo "9"; }

$dispatch = array(
    0=>"foo0",
    1=>"foo1",
    2=>"foo2",
    3=>"foo3",
    9=>"foo9"
);

foreach ($a as $i)
{
    $dispatch[$i]();
}
```

The above code is faster, but not completely efficient. To improve performance you would have to drop the key look up in the $dispatch array, and move forward each time the value of $a[#] changed. This assumes your $dispatch array matches the input array. You would only gain a performance improvement if the $dispatch array was very large.

```php
$a = array(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,9,9,9);

function foo0()  { echo "0"; }
function foo1()  { echo "1"; }
function foo2()  { echo "2"; }
function foo3()  { echo "3"; }
function foo9()  { echo "9"; }

$dispatch = array(
    0=>"foo0",
    1=>"foo1",
    2=>"foo2",
    3=>"foo3",
    9=>"foo9"
);

reset($dispatch);
$foo = (string)current($dispatch);
$last = 0;
foreach ($a as $i)
{
    $foo();
    if($i != $last)
    {
        $foo = (string)next($dispatch);
        $last = $i;
    }
}
```

That should be about as efficient as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how different this is from The Solution's, but I'd thought I'd throw it out there.

```
function func1 () {
    echo "hi\n";
}
function func2 () {
    echo "bye\n";
}
$functionList = array (
    0 => "func1",
    1 => "func2"
);
$a = array(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,9,9,9);
$len = count($a);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if (isset($functionList[$i])) {
        call_user_func($functionList[$i]);
    }
}
```

I set the keys of `$functionList` explicitly, since OP says they will not always be numeric. Perhaps the first 2-3 assignments could be wrapped into a class.

Answer (score 0):

This verbose solution will prevent any `if` condition from being run after it has evaluated to false and will not iterate over the same `$i` value more than once except for when it transitions to the next loop.

```
for($i=0; i<count($a); i++) {
    if($firstCondition) {
        //do something
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

for($i; i<count($a); i++) {
    if($secondCondition) {
        //do something
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```